# Django channels sends 403 instead of 404

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I'm just starting with django channels and I would like in case of error that django channels sends a 404 instead of a 403 when closing without accepting connection.

```
class MyConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        if False:
            await self.accept()
        await self.close()
```

Client side, when I connect to this socket, I get 403 and I want to receive 404:

```
b'HTTP/1.1 403 Access denied\r\n'
```

There is probably something basic I don't get.

Edit:
I may be wrong but I'm supposed to follow this.
From ocpp1.6j: https://www.openchargealliance.org/downloads/

> 3.2. Server response
>
> Upon receiving the Charge Point’s request, the Central System has to finish the handshake with a response as described in [RFC6455].
> The following OCPP-J-specific conditions apply:
>
> • If the Central System does not recognize the charge point identifier in the URL path, it SHOULD
> send an HTTP response with status 404 and abort the WebSocket connection as described in
> [RFC6455].

Comment: Yeah, based on HTTP statuses, it definitely shouldn't be 404. 404 is used when a requested resource is not found but in this case, the server decides to deny the websocket  connection request(which is a HTTP protocol upgrade request) so it is quite correct that you receive a 403. I advise that you use the correct status code instead of trying to reconfigure it

Comment: In my case, the denial of resource is because the resource does not exist. It's not a matter of authentication for example. The request the client made was incorrect.

Comment: Please link the source you quoted so I can check it.

Comment: And please not that the OCPP is enitrely a different protocol with some part of it based on the websocket protocol. So you shouldn't really expect a more generic ws protocol to follow this specific protocol

Comment: I added the link

Comment: After checking the RFC for websockets here https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#page-43, they did make mention of returning the appropriate http status based on the reason for the denial and mentioned both 403 and 404. It seems that by default, channels(or the underlying ASGI server) returns 403 if a connection  is denied, so the question is how to specify the particular status to be returned. I will try to check that later and update you with my findings

Comment: Thank you ! I'm waiting for your answer. I couldn't find the solution :/

Comment: According to this comment in the repo, it seems like only 403 is issued from channels. 404 is only issued if the url does not match and the websocket handshake is not initiated. https://github.com/django/daphne/issues/114#issuecomment-301328780